# How to selector ID textbox array using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, textinput

I have the HTML code

```html
<input id="info[text1]" type="text" value="1"/> <br>
<input id="info[text2]" type="text" value="2"/> <br>
```

I want to select `id='info[text1]'` using jquery but I can't, so can you help me?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Those are valid IDs in HTML5.

Comment: @undefined, thanks for a tip. +1 to OP :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to escape the brackets with `\\`

```
$("#info\\[text1\\]")
```

see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (second paragraph)

Comment: using PHP EOT you need 3 backslashes \\\

Answer (score 5):

Try it this way.

```
$('input[id="info[text1]"]')
```

Comment: Worked for me, add colon before `input` and it works even better ;) $(':input[id="info[text1]"]') - nice one!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#info\\[text1\\]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwrVn/