# multiple usercontrols in a page in jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user-control in which I have a `textbox`. I am using jQuery auto-fill in this text-box.

When I use this user-control on a page multiple times, it doesn't work. I know its because of repeat ids of `textbox` but I am not getting how to solve this problem. Help me please .

Here is my UserContol

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Classes.ascx.cs" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClass" placeholder="search Class" type="text" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
    ClientIDMode="Static" Width="250px" OnTextChanged="txtClass_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#txtClass").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var oClass = $("#txtClass").val().replace('*', '');
                .
                .
                .
                .
                }
            });
        }
```

**Update**

here is html

```
    <input name="ctl00$BodyContent$txtClassasd$txtClass" id="txtClass" placeholder="search Class" type="text" style="width:250px;" />

<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#txtClass").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var test = document.getElementById("txtClass").value;
                var oClass = $("#txtClass").val().replace('*', '');



<input name="ctl00$BodyContent$Classes1$txtClass" id="txtClass" placeholder="search Class" type="text" style="width:250px;" />
<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#txtClass").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var oClass = $("#txtClass").val().replace('*', '');
```

Comment: How is your `txtClass` repeated? Can you show us those codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ClientID for server controls

```
 $("#<%=txtClass.clientID%>").autocomplete(
```

also remove ClientIDMode="Static" from the txtClass control

Comment: oh remove that attribute ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html that is emitted to the browser, I'm guessing there is not actually a textbox with ID of 'txtClass'. You should be doing something like `$("#<%= txtClass.ClientID %>")...`

Answer (score 0):

Use ID array:

[How to selector ID textbox array using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973281/how-to-selector-id-textbox-array-using-jquery)

Or revise your selector

```
$("input").autocomplete({...
```